# Is there a diff in the new iphone versus previous version (development perspective)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I get an iphone, should I go for the latest version (with the antenna issue) or can I make do just fine with the previous version?

i.e. are there significant O/S changes that will effect my ability to test and run an iphone application?

Comment: The antenna issue is overblown.  If I lick my finger and put it right on the antenna gap, I lose about one bar of coverage, and other phones seem to be more or less affected.  I was going to get a case for it anyway, and a case (or even the little band that goes around the edge) solves the problem.

Comment: david, do you work for apple? j/k

Answer (score 1):

A previous version (3g or 3gs) can still run the latest O/S (4.0.2), the only things truly different programmatically for the iPhone 4 is the higher pixel count and resolution of the screen, the new camera, and the new/improved gyro/accelerometer.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 3G can't do multitasking. If you want to test your app's multitasking capabilities, you'll need at least an iPhone 3GS or the latest generation of iPod Touch.